# How to make label in st.multiselect bigger/bolder

Tags: python, markdown, streamlit

I am looking to make the label of multiselect bigger / bolder, my code looks like this :

```
choice_mode = st.multiselect("Chose Mode", ['A','B','C'], default="*")
```

I have tried adding this :

```
st.markdown(".stTextInput > label {font-size:105%; font-weight:bold; color:blue;} ",unsafe_allow_html=True) #for all text-input label sections

st.markdown(".stMultiSelect > label {font-size:105%; font-weight:bold; color:blue;} ",unsafe_allow_html=True) #for all multi-select label sections
```

from this page : https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/the-problem-changing-label-font-of-text-input-and-multi-select/23329

but all it does is display the text on my app like so :
[image]

Am I doing this wrong? Could it be the streamlit version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the css in `<style>`. You can write both css in one `markdown` instead of having to repeat yourself.
**Note:** It's a good practice to keep your code properly formatted, that will save you headache in the long run, when you are looking to refacture the code.

```py
st.markdown("""
    <style>
        .stTextInput > label {
            font-size:105%; 
            font-weight:bold; 
            color:blue;
        }
        .stMultiSelect > label {
            font-size:105%; 
            font-weight:bold; 
            color:blue;
        } 
    </style>
    """, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```